# Sort the integers of a txt file in another file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filewriter

I have to sort every integers of a file called "file_1.txt" in another file called "file_2.txt", but when I compile it does nothing.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public static void main(String[] args){

    try
    {   
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("D:\\file_1.txt"));
    while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
        Scanner lineScanner= new Scanner(fileScanner.nextLine());
        while (lineScanner.hasNext() && lineScanner.hasNextInt())
        {
            try{
            FileWriter file=new FileWriter("D:\\file_2.txt");
            BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(file);
            int s = lineScanner.nextInt();
            writer.write(s);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.close();
            file.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }lineScanner.close();

    }fileScanner.close();
}

    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code line by line to see what happens?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I would suggest you to google how to read a file using java, how to write a file using java and how to sort integers using java. There are literally hundreds of tutorial out there for each of these.

Comment: Does nothing? You are at least opening a file, so something **is done**

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a file for **every line** of the first file. You don't want to do that...

Here's the general overview of what you should be doing.

1) Load all numbers from one file into a List.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("D:\\file_1.txt"));
while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(fileScanner.nextLine());
}
```

2) Sort the numbers

```
Collections.sort(numbers);
```

3) Write the list to a new File

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("D:\\file_2.txt"))) {
    for (int x : numbers) {
        pw.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into `HashSet` that will automatically maintain sorted the integers and then write it into another file.

```
// Hashset maintains the sorted list
Set<Integer> integers = new HashSet<Integer>();
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("D:\\file_1.txt"));
while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
{
    integers.add(Integer.parseInt(fileScanner.nextLine());
}

try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("D:\\file_2.txt"))) 
{
    for (int integer : integers) 
    {
       writer.println(integer);
    }
}
```